# datagridview data to textbox

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, datagridview

Hi i have problem in this code it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

i have a textbox for search,a datagridview and 7 textboxes for the items info.
if i type the word in search texboxes and the datagridview shows the match item but when i clicked the datagridview it shows the error..

```
 Private Sub Supplies_RegularDataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Supplies_RegularDataGridView1.CellClick
    Supplies_RegularDataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected = True
    Dim i = Supplies_RegularDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    TextBox1.Text = Supplies_RegularDataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value.ToString()
    TextBox2.Text = Supplies_RegularDataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value.ToString()
    TextBox3.Text = Supplies_RegularDataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value.ToString()
    TextBox4.Text = Supplies_RegularDataGridView1.Item(4, i).Value.ToString()
    TextBox5.Text = Supplies_RegularDataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value.ToString()
    TextBox14.Text = Supplies_RegularDataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value.ToString()
    TextBox6.Text = Supplies_RegularDataGridView1.Item(7, i).Value.ToString() =the error here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Supplies_RegularDataGridView1.Item(7, i).Value` is null

in c#  you may do the following:

```
Supplies_RegularDataGridView1.Item(7, i).Value!=null?Supplies_RegularDataGridView1.Item(7, i).Value:"";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this code
     Dim I%
     DataGridView2.Item(0, I).Value = Text1.Text
     DataGridView2.Item(1, I).Value = Text2.Text
     DataGridView2.Item(2, I).Value = Text3.Text
     DataGridView2.Item(3, I).Value = Text4.Text
     DataGridView2.Item(4, I).Value = Text5.Text
```